# How to get SAPUI5 namespace in controller?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

Dear SAP Fiori developers,

How can I get the App namespace in JavaScript classes? I mean it seems in `data-sap-ui-resourceroots` inside of index.html we define the namespace statically. How can I access this namespace in Javascript controller classes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why exactly do you need this and what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to create a class and use it in different Apps. But I don't want to everytime need to change the static strings in the classes when I copy and past this controller file. I want to write the controller somehow generic to be able to copy anywhere. By the way Mr.Nabi I saw your blog. It is pretty good but its data is a little bit old. I left some comments there but it seems you don't take care of them. I think it is good to update them based on XML view.

Comment: Yesterday there was another answer which is not available anymore. Based on the question and the additional details I belive that one answer could have been right, although you didn't accept it. I think it makes sense to add some more details, maybe even code samples. What confuses me is "copy and paste". Are you expecting to really copy and paste code? That sounds like a bad approach. And again, the guy who answered had the right solution for you!

And: You have left exactly one comment about an uncritical typo 4 months ago on one of my tutorials. I've replied just now.

Comment: Dear cakino, it was a good decision. Because even wrong answers help for understanding.

Comment: thumbs up for restoring! Thanks, Jaro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might define the namespace as a constant value and use this constant in component.js :

```
var __NAMESPACE = "sap.ui.demo.toolpageapp.";
…
return UIComponent.extend(__NAMESPACE + "Component", {
```

This kind of replacement would work in javascript coding and javascript views.
It will not work with xml-files and manifest-files.
Also xml-views are recommended.

Another option would be to use an editor, where you can search and replace in all files of your app simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Fiori app did not use `index.html` as an entry file, it access Component.js directly. So my idea is get namespace from manifest.json. I chose `rootView` descriptor.

```
//any.controller.js
_getNamespace: function() {
    //namespace.App
    var oViewName = this.getOwnerComponent().getMetadata().getRootView().viewName;

    return oViewName.split(".")[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the object of `window["sap-ui-config"]` resourceroots. See document at [Configuration of the OpenUI5 Runtime](https://openui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f08de06f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html)

Comment: The solution can be correct as while as I have index.html file. As soon as I remove it like the fiori app that do not have index.html anymore then this solution doesn't work.

Comment: Also I have to enter the 'resourceroots' in 2 places.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your resource roots in the index.html as you proposed:

```
<script src="https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/1.38.12/resources/sap-ui-core.js" 
                id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
                data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
                data-sap-ui-preload="async" 
                data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
                    "fiori": "./",
                    "abc": "../abc_web/lib/",
                    "def": "../def_web/"
                }'
                > 
        </script>
```

Let's say you need to use some function from mathLib.js (which is situated in the /abc_web/lib/mathLib.js) in your controller (called App.controller.js). You can acces it as follows:

```
        sap.ui.define([ 
        "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",    
        "abc/mathLib", 

        ], function(Controller, CallItAsYouWant) {
           "use strict";    
           return Controller.extend("fiori.controller.App", {
              onInit: function () {
                 ...your code
                 CallItAsYouWant.someFunction();                     
              }
              ...
```

Comment: Dear Sir. It was not my question. I know how to call a function from some other controllers. I want to catch the namespace programmatically and not store it in a string. In this way when I copy the file in some other programmes I don't need to update those strings times to times.